# X-ray imaging of coconut

Tags: x-rays

I'm doing the X-ray imaging of a coconut with soft X-rays. But the images have no contrast between the rice and water inside the coconut. How can I adjust the parameters to see this contrast inside the coconut? Horizontal and vertical projection settings for different images (parameters are the same)? Why is that?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: What parameters can you change? A short description of the setup would be very informative.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be a technical question about imaging and not about the physical process behind it. If it is, please rephrase the question.

Comment: You say "rice" in the context of coconuts like it's terminology that this site's audience (or indeed any general audience of physicists) will understand without you needing to explain. It's not.

Comment: Your image seems to have uploaded incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

I should note first that I don't quite understand what exactly you are doing. Are you trying to get images of a whole coconut or of a half coconut? And what does rice have to do with that? Do you just put some rice inside a half coconut?

Nevertheless, let me try to offer some tips to get better contrast. If you cannot use a different wavelength range, you can use the same trick that doctors do: use some contrast (dye), such as barium or water-soluble iodine. If you have a whole coconut, you can drill a narrow hole in the coconut, inject the contrast (for example, using a syringe), and shake the coconut.

I hope you follow all the safety rules working with ionizing radiation, such as X-rays, and the dye.

EDIT (7/17/2019): Your deleted answer gave more information. So it looks like you want a method to tell a normal coconut from a macapuno. Some non-X-ray methods may be more promising, for example, ultrasound testing or rotation (the same method that is used to tell a boiled egg from a raw egg).